# Change the column background colour based on Ajax return

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to change the background colour of a dataTables column based on the return of an ajax return.

If the ajax return ("MessageCount" => $MessageCount);( = 0, I would like the background colour of the column to be green, else be red.

The Ajax

```
$sql = "SELECT h.deviceName, h.messageCount, c.DisplayDescription
FROM ConfMainDisplayBoards2017 AS c 
Left Join FIDS_Hardware AS h 
ON c.DisplayID = h.ConfDeviceID 
WHERE  h.ConfDeviceID IS NOT NULL
AND c.HotelID = '".$_SESSION['_amember_user']['hotelid']."' 
AND h.hotelID2 = '".$_SESSION['_amember_user']['hotelid']."'
ORDER BY h.orderby ASC";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($conn));
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
  $DisplayDescription = $row['DisplayDescription'];
  $DeviceName    = $row['deviceName'];
  $MessageCount  = $row['messageCount'];
  $data[] = array("DisplayDescription" => $DisplayDescription,
           "DeviceName"   => $DeviceName,
           "MessageCount" => $MessageCount);
                    
}
 echo json_encode($data);
```

The jQuery/dataTables

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var table = $('#WayFinderStatusTable').DataTable( {      
   ordering: false,
   paging: false,
   searching: false,
   bInfo : false,
   responsive: true,
   fixedHeader: true,
   scrollX: false,
   pageResize: true,
   ajax: {
      url: 'check_wayfinder_status.php', 
      dataSrc: ''
   },
    columns: [
      { data: 'DisplayDescription' },
      { data: 'DeviceName' },
      { data: 'MessageCount' },
    ],
     
   // rowCallback: function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
      //if ( data[2] != 0" ) {        
        //$(row).addClass('red');
     // } else {
        //$(row).addClass('green');
      //}
    //},

  rowCallback: function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
    if ( data[2] === "normal" ) {        
      $(row).find('td:eq(0)').css('background-color','green');
    } else {
      $(row).find('td:eq(0)').css('background-color','red');  
    }
  },
    columnDefs: [
    { className: "WayFinderOverrideStatusTable", "targets": [ 0 ] },
    { "visible": false, "targets": 1 },
    { "visible": false, "targets": 2 },
    ],
    
   fnRowCallback: function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
     $('td', nRow).attr('nowrap','nowrap');
     return nRow;
   }
  });
  setInterval( function () {
    table.ajax.reload();
  }, 30000 );
});
```

The CSS

```
.red {
  background-color: red !important;
}

.green {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Row in rowCallback gives you the complete row. You have to extract the column from it

```
$(row).find('td:eq(2)').css('background-color','green');
```

for example. (You can of course use add class or whatever you like to change the column)

Comment: Hi, I have change the code ( see edit ) but this is not working. I have obviously not got the code right. Can yu see where I am going wrong. Many thanks.

Comment: Please try $(row).find('td:eq(2)').html('Test'); if that changes anything

Comment: Hi and sorry for not getting back sooner. I have found the issue as to why the script is not doing as required. The part of the script where I have " if ( data[2] === "normal" ) { " is not getting triggered. So I am going to completely rewrite the post to try and make it easier to read. I am going to delete this post and resubmit using a clearer way of explaining it.